# Storing an object into a list doesn't work in Java?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble retreiving data from a list. The values never seem to get stored, or the object is initialized?
I made a class that stores some variables:

```
public class storage{
     public int a = 0;
     public int b = 0;
}
```

then I created another class which fills a, and b with some values and stores the object in a list

```
public class anotherclass{
      public List<storage> alldata = new ArrayList<storage>();

      public void filldata(){
            storage tmp = new storage();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
                 tmp.a = i;
                 tmp.b = i;
                 alldata.add(tmp);
            }
      }
}
```

but when I run filldata() in my main class, then try to get the object from the list a and b are still set at 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    anotherclass obj = new anotherclass();
    obj.filldata()

    for (int i = 0; i <= obj.alldata.size() - 1; i++){
          System.out.println(obj.alldata.get(i).a)
          System.out.println(obj.alldata.get(i).b)
          //Outputs as all zeroes
    }

}
```

How could this be?

Comment: What is the `storage` class doing? (Also, it's usually better to capitalize the beginning of your class names)

Comment: First thing I would like to say is, class names should always begin with a Caps letter. *Sigh* And what is this *public static main()* - Post the exact code which gave the error. Don't type the code here manually.

Comment: You can use enhanced for-loop when getting all items from list

Comment: sorry, I typed this up really quick. I wanted the storage class to act like a c struct. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: This shouldn't explain the 0s, but you're adding the same instance of the storage class every iteration of the loop.  In other words your ArrayList just has 10 references to the same object.

Comment: Odd thing is it should print out all 10's not all 0's.

Comment: Oh I'm wrong. My bad. Deleted. Thought `new storage()` is within the loop :)

Comment: @MikeGodin Yeah definitely, this must not be the right code as someone else indicated.

Comment: Try printing out the `storage` object instead of its members. The default `toString` includes the address.

Comment: @Mike Godin yes you're right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to create the object every time. otherwise it use the same object. So only it wont add into your list.

```
            storage tmp = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                 tmp = new storage();
                 tmp.a = i;
                 tmp.b = i;
                 alldata.add(tmp);
            }
```

instead of

```
            storage tmp = new storage();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                 tmp.a = i;
                 tmp.b = i;
                 alldata.add(tmp);
            }
```

Comment: That's my thought as well, but it doesn't explain why he's currently getting all 0's instead of all 10's (which is what -should- come from the posted code).  I suspect something is missing

Comment: The OP's posted code is pseudo-code (I see lots of syntax errors in the main method).  Maybe "all zeros" is just a pseudo-result?

Comment: @MikeGodin I know, they missed something if we mentioned that they simply edited and modified. After they commented still i am getting the sample problem.

Answer (score 2):

The below line should be within your `for` loop in the `filldata()` method.

```
storage tmp = new storage();
```

because everytime you need to create a new object to add to your list. In your case, the same object is getting overridden with the new values.

Also, the syntax for your `main` method is wrong. It should be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

**Side Note:** Copy paste the erroneous code from the IDE as such. Please don't type it here. There are so many compilation problems with your code(syntax mistakes, missing semi-colons, etc.). The reason I'm saying this is because the solution I mentioned is for a case where you get all *10*s as output and not *0*s. If you're getting *0*s, then the code you've posted is not the one giving that problem.

Comment: you main method and OP's main method looks same

Comment: @javaBeginner - The OP edited that. Look at the edit history of the question!

Comment: just show the answers and the question and got doubt so asked

Comment: @javaBeginner - Np:) But the code OP has posted still doesn't correspond to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pointer flaw in your filldata() method. You only created one object tmp and you added the same object to your whole list. All the entries in your list point to the same object. To resolve your issue, you should start by creating a new object for each of the entries.

Replace your filldata() with:

```
public void filldata(){
        storage tmp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
             tmp = new storage();
             tmp.a = i;
             tmp.b = i;
             alldata.add(tmp);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your program it prints all 10s (and not 0s as you say it) which is error. Modify as per the answer from @newuser

```
import java.util.*;

class storage{
     public int a = 0;
     public int b = 0;
}

public class anotherclass{
      public List<storage> alldata = new ArrayList<storage>();

      public void filldata(){
            storage tmp = new storage();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
                 tmp.a = i;
                 tmp.b = i;
                 alldata.add(tmp);
            }
      }

public static void main(String[] args){
    anotherclass obj = new anotherclass();
    obj.filldata();

    for (int i = 0; i <= obj.alldata.size() - 1; i++){
          System.out.println(obj.alldata.get(i).a);
          System.out.println(obj.alldata.get(i).b);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should help you, even the code above has got inner class static reference errors.
Below example has `new storage();` with the `for` loop which creates a new object and takes new *a and b* values on every iteration.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StackClass {

class Storage {

    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;
}

public class AnotherClass {

    public List<Storage> allData = new ArrayList<Storage>();

    public void fillData() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Storage tmp = new Storage();
            tmp.a = i;
            tmp.b = i;
            allData.add(tmp);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StackClass stack = new StackClass();
    AnotherClass obj = stack.new AnotherClass();        

    obj.fillData();

    for (int i = 0; i <= obj.allData.size() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Objec[" + i + "].a-" + obj.allData.get(i).a);
        System.out.println("Objec[" + i + "].b-" + obj.allData.get(i).b);

    }
}
}
```